# Table View Cell/UITextField/UIControlEvent

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I was able to get the text fields to populate as subviews in my table view for the login. Now I want to reference the username text field and password text field in my login action however the action can not find the variables of the text fields (username and password) PLEASE HELP! This has been driving me nuts! Here is my code.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString *CellIdentifier = [self.menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        UITextField *username = [[UITextField alloc] init];
        username.frame = CGRectMake(10, 6, 280, 30);
        username.placeholder = @"Username";
        cell.tag = 0;
        [username addTarget:self action:@selector(login:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:username];
    } else {
        UITextField *password = [[UITextField alloc] init];
        password.frame = CGRectMake(10, 6, 280, 30);
        password.placeholder = @"Password";
        cell.tag = 1;
        [password addTarget:self action:@selector(login:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [password setSecureTextEntry:YES];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:password];
    }




    return cell;


}
```

As you can see I created the text fields username and password. However the variables are not being referenced in the action! Anytime the word "username" or "password" shows up, it says "use of undeclared identifier username"/"use of undeclared identifier password". Your help will be greatly appreciated!

```
-(IBAction)login:(id)sender {

    if ([username.text isEqualToString:@""] || [password.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!" message:@"Please fill in all the fields!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }

    {
        NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mysite.com/myfile.php?username=%@&password=%@",username.text, password.text];

        NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

        NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"%@", strResult);

        NSString *cont11 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mysite.com/myfile.php?username=%@&password=%@",username.text, password.text];

        NSData *cont12 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:cont11]];


        NSString *cont13 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:cont12 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"%@", cont13);

        if ([strResult isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {


            UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard=[UIStoryboard
                                          storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];

            AdminPanel *mainView=[mainStoryboard
                                              instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"admin"];

            mainView.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

            [self presentViewController:mainView animated:YES completion:nil];

        }else
        {
            // invalid information
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!" message:@"You must have entered something wrong! Try again!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
            return;

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you want username and password for getting username and password values???

Comment: The sender will be the textField that ended editing, so you can replace username.text with sender.text -- for that to work, you should also change the signature of the method to -(IBAction)login:(UITextField *)sender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create the variables under @interface in your .m file:

```
@interface YourViewController ()
{
       UITextField *username;
       UITextField *password;
}
```

Then take out "UITextField" when you init these variables.